# Can't exchange tail node and first node in circular linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, circular-list

The function I get trouble is `void swapTailAndHead`. My linked list struct just has a pointer `Node* tail`.

main.cpp:

```cpp
void swapTailtoHead()
{
    if(tail == NULL)
        return;
    else if(justHaveTail())
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(countNode() == 2)
    {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* current = tail;
        while(current->next != tail)
            current=current->next;
        current->next = tail->next;
        tail = current->next;
        //std::cout<<current->data;
        tail->next = current->next->next;
        current = current->next->next;
    }
}
```

My test case input is `1 2 3 4`
and my error output is `2 3 1`

I want exchange node not exchange data.
my input `1 2 3 4` and I want my out is `4 2 3 1`

Comment: You want to swap `tail` and `current`. After that, the new `tail` (which seems to be global variable that would better be named `head`) is `current`. You also need to change three internal links: `current->next`, `tail->next` and the link from the node that was before `current`. That means that you must also keep track of that, which you don't.

Comment: From what i understand, given 1->2->3 you need to return 3->2->1,if not this can you illustrate with and example what do you want

Comment: yes that is what I want and more I want exchange node not exchange data

Comment: I think you're losing the element here: `current->next = tail->next;` `tail = current->next;`.   Before you overwrote tail it was the last remaining pointer to number 4. Can you explain how your logic is supposed to work?

Comment: I just want exchange 'Node* tail' into first and vice versa. I really don't know where i wrong, maybe it is about my logic